# Access single image-pixel, matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i want to change every single pixel, so it's "255 - pixel".
i want to do it in for-loop (!).

my code till now:

```
for n=1:1:512 %it's a 512x512 image
     picture = 255 - picture;
end
```

but i don't know how to change single pixel by single pixel in the image.

so what do I need to change "picture" to in my code?

sorry for poor english. also i'm a total newbie.

thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on using a for-loop, to calculate the complement to a number for each element of a general array:

```
for n=1:numel(picture)
  picture(n) = 255 - picture(n);
end
```

Or, if you need a nested loop for a two-dimensional array:

```
for n=1:size(picture,1)
  for m=1:size(picture,2)
    picture(n,m) = 255 - picture(n,m);
  end
end
```

However, this is really abuse of Matlab. A big part of why one would want to use Matlab is *exactly* to avoid for-loops such as these. Instead, you should simply:

```
picture = 255 - picture
```

Comment: for what stands "numel"? it was an exercise in university and said exclusively to use a loop, but in the second exercise it said to do it like the way you suggested (matrix operations)

Comment: I imagined that this might be part of an exercise. [`numel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) counts the number of elements in an array. The first example uses this together with [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) to access all elements of the array, regardless of its shape. It's useful to consult Matlab's documentation, specifically the section about [fundamentals](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/language-fundamentals.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not using any for loop if you want to change the whole picture. 
Just:

```
picture = 255 - picture;
```

Matlab is faster if it does not have to work in loops;

If you need to modify it in for loop and the picture is typical RGB format the picture size is 512x512x3

```
for a=1:512
    for b=1:512
       for c=1:3
           picture(a,b,c) = 255 - picture(a,b,c); 
       end
    end
end
```